# Topologically finitely generated non-abelian isomorphic absolute Galois groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field of positive characteristic and $L$ be a field of characteristic zero.

Assume the absolute Galois groups of $K$ and $L$ are topologically finitely generated, non-abelian and isomorphic as topological groups.

Can $L$ contain a Noetherian unital subring $R\subsetneq L$ not contained in any subfield $F\subsetneq L$?